# Replay messages in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am working with kafka in spring boot, and I am trying to add a functionality that will allow us to start up a service and have it replay messages back to a certain time.

The consumer is setup like this

```
public interface ProductScenarioStream {
    String SERVICE_REQUESTS_PRODUCT_PRICE = "serviceRequestsProductPrice";
    String SERVICE_CONCLUDES_PRODUCT_SCENARIO = "serviceConcludesProductScenario";

    @Output(SERVICE_REQUESTS_PRODUCT_PRICE)
    MessageChannel serviceRequestsProductPrice();

    @Input(SERVICE_CONCLUDES_PRODUCT_SCENARIO)
    SubscribableChannel serviceConcludesProductScenario();
}
```

And

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(ProductScenarioStream.class)
@Profile("stream")
public class ProductStreamServiceImpl implements ProductStreamService 
{
    @Resource
    private ProductScenarioStream productScenarioStream;

    @Override
    public void send(final ServiceRequestsProductPrice event) {
     ...
    }
 }
```

Do you know where I could find the settings to allow me to rewind the offset on the stream in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean `replay` not `reply` - I have edited your question.

Spring Cloud Stream does not currently expose a mechanism to seek the offsets.

You can use spring-kafka's `@KafkaListener` instead; implement `ConsumerSeekAware` which gives you the mechanism to seek during startup (or any time).